# jQuery for each

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery variable like this:

```
var variable = $j(this).val();
```

Where $j(this) is the "numeric" value of a select option.

What I want to do is loop through the variable value i.e do something once,twice etc, based on the value of the variable.  A bit like this:

```
$j.each(variable, function() {
   do something
});
```

But it does not do it, which bit is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Does `this` refer to an `<option value="...">` or to a `<select>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for ( var i = 0; i< variable; i++ ) { }
```

Assuming `variable` is something like `5`.

Comment: Remember that `i` is still global to the function; it is not scoped to the block!

Answer (score 4):

Use a for loop instead

```
for (i = 0; i < variable; i++)
{
    // do something 
}
```

jQuery's each is for looping through a collection (objects or arrays).

Comment: This performs an action `variable + 1` times.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(’selector’).each(function(index){
// Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery iterates over a collection; it does not know how to handle "iterating" over a Number.

Instead, you can try a classic for loop:

```
var variable = $j(this).val(), i;

for (i = 0; i < variable; ++i) {
    // do something
}
```

If you still want to handle the jQuery-like syntax, you could extend `$j.each`:

```
(function ($) {
    var oldEach = $.each;

    $.each = function (index, func) {
        var i;

        if (typeof index === 'number') {
            for (i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
                func.call(null, i);
            }
        } else {
            oldEach.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
})($j);
```

Comment: Over-complicating a simple problem?

Comment: @Marko Ivanovski, Not really.  I guess jQuery is "over-complicating a simple problem" by having `$.each` in the first place, huh?

Comment: "Marko Ivanovski & @Strager Actually foreach is over complicating, didn't think to do for - durrr in php I'd have done for instantly! Thanks for reolies. Russell

Comment: Can you also provide code for implementing the `if` statement in jQuery style? I want to say `$('#id').if(...`, because I really like the dollar signs and the chaining, and the classic `if` statement is just so...old-fashioned.